# Postgres: Performance Issue: Query on enormous data fails to use index

Tags: postgresql, performance, index

This is the schema of `task_statuses` table

```
                         Table "public.task_statuses"
     Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id             | uuid                        |           | not null | 
 updated_at     | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 status         | task_status                 |           | not null | 
 status_details | json                        |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "task_statuses_id_updated_at_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id, updated_at)
    "idx_task_statuses_id_updated_at" btree (id, updated_at)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "task_statuses_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES tasks(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The table however is huge and has 150GB of data in production.
I am trying to run an extremely simple query

```sql
 SELECT 
            ts.id
        FROM task_statuses ts
        WHERE 
            ts.status IN ('succeeded', 'failed', 'cancelled') 
        ORDER BY ts.id, ts.updated_at desc LIMIT 1000
```

It keeps timing out in production. When I remove `ORDER BY` the query runs successfully. Since, I have index in `id and udpated_at`, I am not sure why `order by` is timing out.

`explain analyse` times out as well.

Here is the `explain` for the above query.

```sql
Limit  (cost=10651159.84..10651276.51 rows=1000 width=24)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=10651159.84..10744721.60 rows=801902 width=24)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=10650159.81..10651162.19 rows=400951 width=24)
              Sort Key: id, updated_at DESC
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on task_statuses ts  (cost=0.00..10628176.10 rows=400951 width=24)
                    Filter: (status = ANY ('{succeeded,failed,cancelled}'::task_status[]))
```

Query plan without order by:

- https://explain.depesz.com/s/CfIU

Helpful links:

- https://explain.depesz.com/s/G3VB
- https://explain.depesz.com/s/hJCL

Suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your costs are on your `WHERE` predicate for `ts.status`.
You can see in the **explain** it's doing a **Seq Scan** for **400,951** rows with a cost of **10,628,176.10**.

While having an index that is based on the `ORDER BY` fields in a query can help performance with the sorting, generally you should focus more on indexing based on your predicates (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, and `HAVING` clauses) because it won't have to do a **Sequential Scan** rather it can use the index to scan or seek even.

In this case if you had an index on the `status` column instead, your performance would likely be better (regardless sorting on your `ORDER BY` clause).

The difference in performance you're currently seeing is probably a difference in **query plan** between when you use and remove the `ORDER BY` clause that happens to be more efficient altogether. If you ran an **explain** for the query without the `ORDER BY` clause, I'm sure you'd see different operations occuring. But again, proper indexing on the `status` field should give you consistency in performance, either way.

Comment: Ironically, removing ORDER BY made postgres use the index.
https://explain.depesz.com/s/CfIU

Comment: @Surya Yes in that case that's why it's more efficient, but it's also using not the best index because the index it's using is on `id, updated_at` when you're filtering on the `status` field. You should create an index on `status` and verify the **explain** shows that new index being used in the query plan, regardless if you are using `ORDER BY`. That theoretically should be more performant for you in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your index (well, both of them, it is not clear why you have two of them which differ only in UNIQUE) is on `(id, created_at)`, but your ORDER BY is on `id, created_at DESC`.

PostgreSQL can follow an index forward, and follow it backwards, but it won't follow one inside out and sideways. Make an index on `(id, created_at DESC)` if you want to have the best hope of following the index to obtain an ordering.

**BUT** in the newest version of PostgreSQL (v13), there is an "incremental sort", which could use the existing index to get rows in order by id, then re-sort within each group of ties by id to put them in order by created_at DESC.  If each group of ties by id is small, this could be pretty efficient.

Comment: That makes sense would try it out.

Comment: Also, thanks for noticing the duplicate index. Fixing that as well.